# Spring Data JPA: case insensitive orderBy

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I want to sort my entities by the *name* attribute with ascending direction and ignoring the case.

I've created an EntityRepository extending the Repository interface of Spring Data. Then I've declared the following find method:

```
List<Entity> findByNameOrderByNameIgnoreCaseAsc(String name);
```

But I get this error "No property ignoreCase found for type".

I can't find any reference to this case in the [Spring Data JPA documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/).

I'm using spring-data-jpa version 1.11.0.

Comment: Try with `findByNameOrderByNameAscIgnoreCase(String name)` ([reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation))

Comment: Does not works: "No property ignoreCase found".

Comment: what version of spring-data-jpa you use? what does your repository class extend? you're not providing enough information in the question.

Comment: What sense does it make to order by name ignoring case when you filter by name not ignoring case?

Answer (score 10):

If you want just to return all entities with sorting by name with ignore case you can use this:

```
repository.findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Order.asc("name").ignoreCase()));
```

Comment: That's nice, because any other method in your repository can receive a `Sort sort` parameter, and you can use the very same solution on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data `IgnoreCase` can be only used for finding by a property, and cannot be user in combination with Order by.

However you can get you results using `Sort.Order.ignoreCase()` and Pages http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.Order.html#ignoreCase--

Answer (score 0):

Try instead creating the  repository method below (notice the added sort parameter)

```
List<Entity> findByName(String name, Sort sort);
```

Then extend the PagingAndSortingRepository in this repository (with Long being whatever your entity id type is):

```
extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Entity, Long>
```

Then call the method as so:

```
repository.findByName("nameToFind", Sort.by(Sort.Order.asc("name").ignoreCase()));
```

Answer (score -3):

Your method should be like this.

```
List<Entity> findByNameIgnoreCaseOrderByNameAsc(String name);
```

Please refer https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: I want to order by name ignoring the case of the name. Your method matches the entities using the name and ignoring the case.