# Where to find examples of how to use sort.order.ignorecase() with nullhandling nulls last to customize how Spring JPA serves up queries

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Since Friday I've been trying to figure out how to make a Spring JPA Query ignore case for first and last name in the ordering it serves up. On Monday, I came across two threads ([here's a link to one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043862/spring-data-jpa-case-insensitive-orderby)) that suggest using Sort.Order.ignoreCase() but haven't been able to figure out how to distill the documentation into working code (clearly I'm a novice). Can anyone point me to some examples online?

In my exact situation, I'm trying to make out so that "Individual" objects with first and lastname properties can be compared first by last name and, if the last names are the same, then by firstname. I also need to avoid a null pointer exception. I did find a way to do this by using Comparator. For my own education, I want to better understand how this Sort.Order.ignoreCase() solution works and see if I can apply it to my situation. I

Answer (score 0):

I ran across a similar situation a while back and I ended up making an Aspect that handled this globally. If you need it on a case by case basis, I don't have an answer for that, but at the very least, maybe this code can get you headed in the right direction.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class SortManipulatingAspect {

    @Around("execution(public * org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository+.*(..))")
    public Object enableIgnoreCaseSorting(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        return joinPoint.proceed(
                Arrays.stream(joinPoint.getArgs()).map(SortManipulatingAspect::sortWithIgnoreCase).toArray()
        );
    }

    private static Object sortWithIgnoreCase(Object arg) {
        if (arg instanceof PageRequest) {
            return pageRequestIgnoreCaseSort((PageRequest)arg);
        } else {
            return arg;
        }

    }

    private static PageRequest pageRequestIgnoreCaseSort(PageRequest pageRequest) {
        return new PageRequest(
                pageRequest.getPageNumber(),
                pageRequest.getPageSize(),
                pageRequest.getSort() != null ? new Sort(toOrderStream(pageRequest.getSort())) : null
        );
    }

    private static List<Sort.Order> toOrderStream(Sort sort) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(sort.spliterator(), false)
                .map(Sort.Order::ignoreCase)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```